# Gaussian Noise using Core Graphics only?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

How would I ever use Core graphics only to generate a noise texture background? I'm stuck on the noise part because there is no way to add a noise filter in core graphics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About a year later, I've found the answer:

```
CGImageRef CGGenerateNoiseImage(CGSize size, CGFloat factor) CF_RETURNS_RETAINED {
    NSUInteger bits = fabs(size.width) * fabs(size.height);
    char *rgba = (char *)malloc(bits);
    srand(124);

    for(int i = 0; i < bits; ++i)
        rgba[i] = (rand() % 256) * factor;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, fabs(size.width), fabs(size.height),
                                                       8, fabs(size.width), colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

    CFRelease(bitmapContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(rgba);

    return image;
}
```

This effectively generates a noise image that's guaranteed to be random, and can be drawn, using the code from Jason Harwig's answer.

Comment: Note that the image returned from this function has a +1 retain count and needs to be released using CFRelease(image) after you're done drawing it. Otherwise, it leaks. Also, the name of the function should be changed to reflect this. It should contain "new" or "create" somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a noise png, then draw it using an overlay blend.

```
// draw background
CGContextFillRect(context, ...)

// blend noise on top
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
CGImageRef cgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noise"].CGImage;
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, cgImage);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
```

Comment: By pure Core Graphics I wanted to draw the noise in Core Graphics as well... My app's requirement is that it uses no png files, sadly.

Comment: That's an odd requirement. I could see resolution independence as the reason, but just using two different resolution pngs will solve that.

Comment: Nonetheless, that would work... Is there a way to hard-encode the UIImage as text data that I could bring back from a custom class? EDIT: Would I not be able to create a custom wrapper class with a base64 encoded sting of the image in Retina format, and write a few simple methods to return the image in any size/format?

Comment: then simply *generate* the CGImage, rather than using a png resource

Answer (score 3):

There is a CIRandomGenerator in [CoreImageFilters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) as of iOS 6.
But bear in mind that this one is not gaussian noise (as it is not in the previous answer).

```
- (UIImage*)linearRandomImage:(CGRect)rect
{
    CIContext *randomContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIFilter *randomGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIColorMonochrome"];
    [randomGenerator setValue:[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"] valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [randomGenerator setDefaults];

    CIImage *resultImage = [randomGenerator outputImage];
    CGImageRef ref = [randomContext createCGImage:resultImage fromRect:rect];
    UIImage *endImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    return endImage;
}
```