# How to apply gaussian noise to an existing image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, gaussian

The only relevant thread I could found is this:
[Gaussian Noise using Core Graphics only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960197/gaussian-noise-using-core-graphics-only)

Which has a solution of creating complete noise using:

```
CGImageRef CGGenerateNoiseImage(CGSize size, CGFloat factor) CF_RETURNS_RETAINED {
    NSUInteger bits = fabs(size.width) * fabs(size.height);
    char *rgba = (char *)malloc(bits);
    srand(124);

    for(int i = 0; i < bits; ++i)
        rgba[i] = (rand() % 256) * factor;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, fabs(size.width), fabs(size.height),
                                                       8, fabs(size.width), colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

    CFRelease(bitmapContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(rgba);

    return image;
}
```

Or another answer that takes a noise image and combine it with an image

```
// draw background
CGContextFillRect(context, ...)

// blend noise on top
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
CGImageRef cgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noise"].CGImage;
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, cgImage);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
```

But I couldn't quite figure out how to take an existing **normal** image and apply gaussian noise to it (with varying amount). Much like Photoshop noise filter.

Comment: What is a "normal" image in this context? Typically you'd do this with CIImage. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/processing_an_image_using_built-in_filters  For a specific example that includes a noise filter, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/simulating_scratchy_analog_film

Comment: @RobNapier Normal just means any image. Like a photograph for example. I took a brief look at the filter api but it doesn’t look like there is Gaussian noise?